# How to concat different map type in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am having different map types like below:

```
MapType(StringType(), StringType())
MapType(StringType(), IntegerType())
MapType(StringType(), DoubleType())
```

How can i concat into one and keeping its type intact ?

Answer (score 1):

You can concat the columns of `maptype` having different key and value types. But post concat spark converts the map key/value types to the highest type it finds.

For example-
If you consider the 3 columns having below types resp.-

```scala
col1 - MapType(StringType(), StringType())
col2 - MapType(StringType(), IntegerType())
col3 - MapType(StringType(), DoubleType())
```

the `map_concat` output will be as below-

```
map_concat(col1, col2, col3) - MapType(StringType(), StringType())
```

Since spark finds the highest type as `StringType` for key and value.

Now,

> Why can't spark keeps the original type intact for key-value pairs?

**Ans-**
Spark stores the MapType as `backed by 2 ArrayData`

```scala
class ArrayBasedMapData(val keyArray: ArrayData, val valueArray: ArrayData) extends MapData {
...
}
```

& ArrayData can't handle the heterogenous type. Hence spark can't keep its original type intact post concatenation.

### Working example for reference

```scala
 val df = spark.sql("select map('a', 'b') as col1, map('c', cast(1 as int)) as col2, " +
      "map(1, cast(2.2 as double)) as col3")
    df.printSchema()
    df.show(false)
    /**
      * root
      * |-- col1: map (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- key: string
      * |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
      * |-- col2: map (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- key: string
      * |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = false)
      * |-- col3: map (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- key: string
      * |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = false)
      *
      * +--------+--------+----------+
      * |col1    |col2    |col3      |
      * +--------+--------+----------+
      * |[a -> b]|[c -> 1]|[d -> 2.2]|
      * +--------+--------+----------+
      */

    val p = df.withColumn("new_col", map_concat($"col1", $"col2", $"col3"))
    p.printSchema()
    p.show(false)

    /**
      * root
      * |-- col1: map (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- key: string
      * |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
      * |-- col2: map (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- key: string
      * |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = false)
      * |-- col3: map (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- key: string
      * |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = false)
      * |-- new_col: map (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- key: string
      * |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
      *
      * +--------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
      * |col1    |col2    |col3      |new_col                   |
      * +--------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
      * |[a -> b]|[c -> 1]|[d -> 2.2]|[a -> b, c -> 1, d -> 2.2]|
      * +--------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
      */
```

### Update-1

**`Use struct to combine columns into one`**

```scala
 val x = df.withColumn("x", struct($"col1", $"col2", $"col3"))
      x.printSchema()
    x.selectExpr("x.col1['a']", "x.col2['c']", "x.col3['d']").printSchema()

    /**
      * root
      * |-- col1: map (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- key: string
      * |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
      * |-- col2: map (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- key: string
      * |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = false)
      * |-- col3: map (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- key: integer
      * |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = false)
      * |-- x: struct (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- col1: map (nullable = false)
      * |    |    |-- key: string
      * |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = false)
      * |    |-- col2: map (nullable = false)
      * |    |    |-- key: string
      * |    |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = false)
      * |    |-- col3: map (nullable = false)
      * |    |    |-- key: integer
      * |    |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = false)
      *
      * root
      * |-- x.col1 AS `col1`[a]: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- x.col2 AS `col2`[c]: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- x.col3 AS `col3`[CAST(d AS INT)]: double (nullable = true)
      */
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have done that only but it keeps map(string,string) however i am looking for type  to be as is as it in in col 1,2,3.Because it will go it stream kafka where  the schema is of same as col1,2,3.But col 3 is changing this.Is theree any other way we can do it of struct or something?

Comment: You can use struct to combine all 3 maptype columns into one column. check update-1. also Feel free to upvote + accept if it helps